# How to inject EAV attribute to product model before loading it in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, eav, magento-2.0.5

I want to always add a specific EAV attribute to the Product model whenever a Product model is loading.

As an example, I always want to include vendor_name and brand_name EAV attributes to my Product model whenever I'm loading any product model anywhere in Magento. Is there any product_before_load observer in Magento 2, so that I will be able to inject my required EAV attributes to product's model ? Or is there any other solution?

I'm in the situation that my products already loaded without those EAV attributes and I just don't want to re-load products (because of performance problems it makes (specially in catalog page, which needs to reload each product)). So I want to make sure that all Product models that I'm getting is always have those specific EAV attributes.

Comment: If a product is loaded it should have all the EAV attributes loaded. Do you mean you get it out from a repository or a collection?

Comment: @RiccardoT I mean I ALWAYS want some of the EAV attributes get loaded (in any situation). (even in repository or collection)

Comment: Use `catalog_product_load_after` for single product or `catalog_product_collection_load_after` for collection. Loading all attributes on collection sometimes lead to a very heavy page load, so be careful.